# Skype bot can not be added to group chat

Tags: skype, botframework, skypedeveloper, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

I'm developing a bot for Skype and enabled setting that allows to add this bot to Group Chats. However, when I click to "Add People" button, I can see only the real people, but Skype Bots are hidden there (even the official ones).

There is [an official doc](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34698/can-i-add-skype-bots-to-a-group-conversation) that Skype bot can be added to the group chat as regular Skype account, but I am not able to do it.

My bot is not published, but one on one conversation works well. Also, in the private chat with Bot I can add people to conversation and thus I can create a group with this bot, but the main question is how to add the bot to the existing group chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to add it to the group by opening **Web Skype** and then opening the private chat with my Bot.

Web Skype showed me a message "Add SkotBot to your contacts" which is very strange because it was already on my contact list. After clicking to this link bot is displayed on the "Add People" list.

Comment: "and then opening the private chat with my Bot" - how did you do that in web Skype? I can't find private chats anywhere. I've added my bot to my contacts but I can't see it anywhere in web Skype.

Answer (score 1):

On the configuration page for Skype on the dev.botframework.com site.  Make sure you've enabled group messaging:

[image]

Additional information about groups on skype can be found [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/getting-started/#groups).

Comment: thanks, but as I said above - I have already done this. This setting is ignored as I can see. Moreover, I can't disable it. I can uncheck, byt after clicking to save button it is again enabled.

Comment: I've repro'd the issue and I'm working with the Skype team to determine what is going on.  Thx

Comment: Can you provide the name of your bot for testing?  Thanks

Comment: finally I was able to add it to the group by opening Web Skype and then opening the private chat with my Bot. Web Skype showed me a message "Add SkotBot to your contacts" which is very strange because it was already on my contact list. After clicking to this link bot is displayed on the "Add People" list. It's definitely a bug

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issues. and I try your method/suggestion above, it works!
the exact steps for other to read on (based on your suggestion)
 1. from Mac Client Skype, I'm using version 7.43 (241) make a 1:1 chat with my bot. (to make it appears on the chat history on web skype later)
 2. login the web skype, it will appear as history/conversation on the left. Message sending is disabled. Clicking on the bot icon appears on the chat screen above, it will open the **profile**
 3. Add the bot to contact.
 4. Then the bot can be added to the existing group conversation, just like add a normal human contact.

It seems to be some bugs in the Skype ecosystem?

Comment: This didn't solve it for me, it's weird. Adding the bot to an existing group just won't do anything (after I did your steps), weirdly the bot disappears again from the Skype Web contacts list after a reload. Using the native Windows Skype client the bot gets added and instantly leaves the group. Creating a new group with the bot and another person worked.