# How to enable group support , and add Skype bot to existing Skype group conversation

Tags: skype, botframework, chatbot

I follow a simple tutorial from Microsoft bot framework v3 guide to make a bot out of their Nodejs sdk. Bot is running, registered (but not published) it can be reached from 1 to 1 Skype conversation, where I have subscribed to my own bot, added to my contact.

But there isn't a + button to add new person to form a group. Neither I could add this bot into a group conversation.

I have enabled the "Group" capabilities in the bot , Skype setting. But it doesn't seems to be solving the problem? .

Comment: I'm unable to see and search any bot from the **https://web.skype.com/en/** either. I try to have a conversion with my bot, it seems it was disabled either. It makes me think whether skype bot is limited to certain regions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, there is someone else successfully add it, by using the web skype.

[Referred solution]
[Skype bot can not be added to group chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509631/skype-bot-can-not-be-added-to-group-chat/41735090#41735090)

That answered my problem above.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you let me know the client platform and version you're using? Also if you are able to share the bot handle I can check the settings for the bot.

Comment: bot handle: michelle-galbot
client platform: mac, version 7.43 (241)
is the adding bot to the existing group is a regional thing? I don't see any option to see some other group enabled bot such as Foursquare to an existing group too.

Comment: It's not a regional thing. I checked your bot on a Windows client and I could add it to a group, so it does have the right capability. I'll raise with the Mac team and see if there's a Mac specific issue.