# Can't add bot to group chat

Tags: botframework

I've created a bot (a simple echo bot) and deployed it to Azure. Everything works well now and I can talk to the bot in the desktop Skype client (Windows 10 app).

However, I can't seem to be able to add the bot to an existing group chat. When I click on the add button the list of contacts to add doesn't have my bot in it, which is weird because I've added it to my contacts.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41644443/249230

^ According to that post I need to create a "private chat" with my bot and then I'll be able to add it to group chats, but I have no idea how to do that.

I haven't published my bot, but I did enable "Allow adding to a group" in bot settings on https://dev.botframework.com.

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Private chat is talking directly to your bot. If you have added it to your contacts, it should be easy to open a direct conversation with it by double clicking.

Then you can add people in the conversation using the top right button:
[image: button add people]

Then you will have your group chat working:

[image: groupChat]

Note for other people asking the same question (but you already mentioned that you did it), **don't forget to activate the group conversation for your bot in botframework portal**, in Skype channel settings

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add a bot to group?:

```
https://telegram.me/[botname]?startgroup=foo
```