# Add bot to existing Skype group chat

Tags: azure, botframework, skype

Is there any way to add a bot (created with Azure) to an existing Skype group chat? I can create new groups with the bot but not add it to a group? I didn't submit to bot for application yet, is this really absolutely necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skype bot can not be added to group chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509631/skype-bot-can-not-be-added-to-group-chat)

Comment: @JJ_Wailes didn't solve it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Add bots button in the group profile you will only be able to look up published bots:

[image]

[image]

However, if you use the Add to Group button in the upper right corner (not available in the mobile client), you can find your bots that are still in preview:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may be weird, but keep in mind that Skype bots are in the process of being deprecated